# How to implement skiplist in java (adding values, checking for values)?

Tags: java, function

I want to write a method that allows me to insert a value to the list (generic implementation). Furthermore i want to check wether a value in already in the list or not. I just want to know wether this is how its supposed to be or not.

In order to check wether a value is already contained within the list:

```
public boolean contains(T value) {
    boolean searchedValue;
    if (head == null || baseListLength == 0) {
        searchedValue= false;
    } else {
        IndexListEntry<T> blub= head;
        while ((blub.next != null) && (blub.next.value.compareTo(value) <= 0)) {
            value= blub.next;
        }
        searchedValue= baseList.contains(value, blub.pointer);
    }
    return searchedValue;
}
```

and to add any value to the list:

```
public boolean addValue(T value) {
    BaseListEntry<T> offs= baseList.add(value);

    if (indexListLength < indexMaxLength) {
        if (head == null) {
            head = new IndexListEntry<T>(value, null, offs);
        } else {
            IndexListEntry<T> temp= head;
            while ((temp.next != null) && (temp.next.value.compareTo(value) < 0)) {
                temp= temp.next;
            }
            if (temp.next == null) {
                temp.next = new IndexListEntry<T>(value, null, offs);
            } else {
                temp.next = new IndexListEntry<T>(value, temp.next, offs);
            }
        }
        indexListLength++;

    } else {

        IndexListEntry<T> currentIndex = head.next;


        int intervalWidth = baseListLength / indexMaxLength;


        int intervalAdj = baseListLength % indexMaxLength;

        int indexPosition = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < indexMaxLength; i++) {
            int rip= 0;

            if (intervalAdj - i >= 0)
                rip= 1;
            indexPosition = indexPosition + intervalWidth + rip;
            BaseListEntry<T> newIndexTarget = baseList.getBaseListEntry(indexPosition);
            currentIndex.pointer = newIndexTarget;
            currentIndex.value = newIndexTarget.value;
            currentIndex = currentIndex.next;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Are there any other methods to accomplish that goal? is my code somewhat correct. I am doubting everything I code right now and I kinda need confirmation from someone who knows more than me about this.

This is of course not everything i got. there are more classes to it but these are not the problem at hand so i dont thnk i need to upload that code as well.

Comment: You have a sorted, linked list where each node only points to the next node and you are using insertion sort when you add a new node to the list. Is that correct?